# RubyOnRails throws "No Route Matches" on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models  buyorder and sellorder.  On my order screen I have a section that shows all orders, i.e. the combination of buy and sell orders.

I get the list of all orders via the command:

```
def self.get_orders(p_uid)
    b = Buyorder.where(“user_id=?”,p_uid).all.to_a
    a = Sellorder.where(“user_id=?”,p_uid).all.to_a
    return a+b
end
```

The controller does:

```
@orders = Order.get_orders(session[:user_id])
```

In my view I do the following:

```
<% for o in @orders %>
    <tr><td> <%= link_to 'Delete', o, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} , :method => :delete %></td> </tr>
<% end %>
```

My routes.rb shows:

```
resources :orders
resources :buyorders
resources :sellorders
```

Both controllers Buyorderscontroller and Sellorderscontroller have

```
def destroy
    ….
end
```

But I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"buyorders", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

The destroy method looks like this:

```
def destroy
    Buyorder.where("id=? and user_id=?",params[:id],session[:user_id]).destroy_all
    flash[:info] = 'Order has been deleted'
    redirect_to main_index_path()
end
```

And rake:routes shows:

```
            buyorders GET    /buyorders(.:format)                 buyorders#index
                      POST   /buyorders(.:format)                 buyorders#create
         new_buyorder GET    /buyorders/new(.:format)             buyorders#new
        edit_buyorder GET    /buyorders/:id/edit(.:format)        buyorders#edit
             buyorder GET    /buyorders/:id(.:format)             buyorders#show
                      PATCH  /buyorders/:id(.:format)             buyorders#update
                      PUT    /buyorders/:id(.:format)             buyorders#update
                      DELETE /buyorders/:id(.:format)             buyorders#destroy
```

Why?

PS: Who is downgrading all the answers as well as the question? This is redicilous. If you think the question is stupid,  then provide a working answer and I will be more than happy to accept a downgrade.

Solution:

The original code of self.get_orders looked like this:

```
a = Buyorder.select('price,open_quantity').where("user_id=?",p_uid).all.to_a
b = Sellorder.joins('currency').select('id,currency1_id,currency2_id,ostatus,price,open_quantity').where("user_id=?",p_uid).all.to_a
```

Once I made the two lines return the identical results with

```
a = Buyorder.joins('currency').select('id,currency1_id,currency2_id,ostatus,price,open_quantity').where("user_id=?",p_uid).all.to_a
b = Sellorder.joins('currency').select('id,currency1_id,currency2_id,ostatus,price,open_quantity').where("user_id=?",p_uid).all.to_a
```

The error disappeared.

In other words, if you combine two array, make sure they are identical in their columns they return.

Comment: What is actually in your `destroy` method?

Comment: I have pasted the content of the destroy method.

Comment: @Kumala Is that the complete code in your view? If not, then do you another `link_to` in your view which is pointing to `show` action. It would be really helpful if you share the complete view code and the server log with error details.

Comment: that looks like it should work, are you 100% sure that is the line tossing the error?

Comment: Yes this is the only link_to statement in the view. The error points to the line <tr><td> <%= link_to 'Delete', o, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} , :method => :delete %></td> </tr>

Comment: and yes that line is causing the error. Once I delete the line, the view renders just fine.

Comment: Put a  'do' at the end of the for o in orders line. It should be optional, but...

Comment: doesnt help. Error is still there.

Comment: The error only appeared after I changed the database model. Previously all orders (buy and sell orders) were in a single table (orders). I am splitting them into two tables, buyorders and sellorders. Thats when the error started showing up. So I assume it has to do with the format of how I return the result from get_orders.

Comment: OK, I got a step further, looks like the problem is in fact in self.get_orders.  For testing purposes I replaced the code there with the single line: return Buyorder.all     In that case the code works.  So it seems that it does not like the return format of that function

Comment: Finally, I figured it out, the solution is too complex for here, so I posted it in the question above. In short: my bad, and I guess I deserve the downgrade.

Comment: With the actual code, I think this could have been solved much quicker. Seeing that, it's obvious that your Buyorder Relation has no id. Also, why the .all after the .where?

Comment: Good point, next time to copy and past rather than typing.

Comment: Why am I using .all?  The next step in the code is to cache the results, thus I have to use .all to get all data so I can push it to memcached and retrieve it at a later point in time from memcached again.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `for` loop in view as

```
<tr><td> <%= link_to 'Delete', o, :method => :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td> </tr>
```

Comment: Thats what I already have, changing the sequence of :method and data: does not fix the error.

Comment: Can you post final html of the link that you are getting on web page now?

Comment: I cant post the HTML because the page doesnt render due to the error.

Comment: I found the solution and have added it to the question for everyones reference.

Answer (score -1):

The *Url helpers* doesn't seem to be able to build the route using the elements of the array you just built.

try this instead:

```
if o.is_a?(Buyorder)
  = link_to 'Delete', buyorder_path(id: o.id), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} , :method => :delete
else
  = link_to 'Delete', sellorder_path(id: o.id), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} , :method => :delete
end
```

Comment: This looks like it should be fine, except it should be buyorder_path(o) instead of order_path(id: o.id).

Comment: Nope, doesnt work. By the way, please be aware the array consists of buyorders and sellorders, an array of differnent classes.

Comment: Updated my answer, does it solve the error on view load?

Comment: I found the solution and have added it to the question for everyones reference.